# adding dyanmic variable to wordpress shortcode to pull number of post

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I created this shortcode to pull a custom post and now I am trying to figure out how to add a variable to the shortcode to pull the number of posts

I placed a variable in the shortcode.

**Shortcode**

```
[gskclasses numberofpost="3"]
```

**Shortcode Function**

```
 $args = array(
 'post_status'=>'publish',
 'post_type'=>array(TribeEvents::POSTTYPE),
 'posts_per_page'=>3,
 //order by startdate from newest to oldest
 'meta_key'=>'_EventStartDate',
 'orderby'=>'_EventStartDate',
 'order'=>'DESC',
 //required in 3.x
 'eventDisplay'=>'custom',
 //query events by category
 'tax_query' => array(
  array(
      'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query'=> array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'classes'
            )
        ),

   ),
   )
   );
```

Comment: If you *created* the shortcode then you must have researched it. If you can research how to make that then surely you would have researched how to add arguments to the shortcode? It's extremely simple. Plus, what you posted is not a *shortcode function*, it's not even a function, but an array.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work,

function my_shortcode( $atts ) {

```
// Set a default, in case the author omits the attribute
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
    'numberofpost' => 3,
), $atts, 'gskclasses' );

$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => array( TribeEvents::POSTTYPE ),

    // Set 'posts_per_page' based on 'numberofpost' attribute
    'posts_per_page' => $atts['numberofpost'],




 $args = array(
'post_status'=>'publish',
'post_type'=>array(TribeEvents::POSTTYPE),
 'posts_per_page'=>3,
  //order by startdate from newest to oldest
 'meta_key'=>'_EventStartDate',
 'orderby'=>'_EventStartDate',
 'order'=>'DESC',
 //required in 3.x
 'eventDisplay'=>'custom',
 //query events by category
 'tax_query' => array(
  array(
      'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query'=> array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'classes'
            )
        ),

  ),
)
);
       );

}
```